# Omitting zeroes from matrix calculation in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, zero, matrix-inverse

I'm performing input-output calculations in Octave. I have several matrices/vectors in the formula:

```
F = f' * (I-A)^-1 * Y
```

All vectors probably contain zeroes. I would like to omit them from the calculation and just return 0 instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Miranda

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "omit them"?

If you want to remove zeros from a vector you can do this:

```
octave:1> x=[1,2,0,3,4,0,5];
octave:2> x(find(x==0))=[]
x =

   1   2   3   4   5
```

The logic is: x==0 will test each element of x (in this case the test is if it equals zero) and will return a vector of 0's and 1's (0 if the test is false for that element and 1 otherwise)

So:

```
octave:1> x=[1,2,0,3,4,0,5];
octave:2> x==0
ans =

   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
```

The find() function will return the index value of any non-zero element of it's argument, hence:

```
octave:3> find(x==0)
ans =

   3   6
```

And then you are just indexing and removing when you do something like:

```
octave:5> x([3, 6]) = []
x =

   1   2   3   4   5
```

But instead you do it with the output of the find() function (which is the vector [3,6] in this case)

You can do the same for matrices:

```
octave:7> A = [1,2,0;4,5,0]
A =

   1   2   0
   4   5   0

octave:8> A(find(A==0))=[]
A =

   1
   4
   2
   5
```

Then use the reshape() function to turn it back into a matrix.